# Deployment Automation, Script incompatibility SSMS and sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-devops, sql-server-2016

I need your experienced advice on automation. I am proficient in Linux, and we are attempting to automate the deployment of Microsoft SQL databases using sqlcmd. The problem arises when using SQL scripts exported from the SSMS GUI. While the script functions properly within SSMS, attempting to execute it with sqlcmd results in numerous errors, presumably due to compatibility issues. As a workaround, I am currently backing up an empty database using sqlcmd and importing it into different servers. However, this approach is not sustainable in the long term.

I believe we have two potential solutions:

1. Export the database schema using sqlcmd (though I am uncertain if this functionality is available, similar to the "--no-data" parameter command in MySQL CLI).
2. Modify the SSMS-exported script to be compatible with sqlcmd (though I suspect this may not be an ideal approach).

Could you please provide any advice based on your experience? How do Windows DevOps professionals typically handle this situation?

Thank you,
Yousuf

Comment: just to be sure: You're talking about automation of MS SQL on Windows Server Hosts, aren't you?